# Call charging for non-answered calls - Twilio

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api

I'm making outgoing browser calls using the code from this [link](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/client/outgoing-calls). I'm using the same code as shown in the link also using twiML app.

I'm using an upgraded twilio account. I tried making call to my number and didn't picked up the call.

1) Why is it showing two entries - Outgoing Dial and Incoming in the call logs even though I'm making an outgoing call only ?

**Call Logs**

```
DATE           DIRECTION        FROM             TO             TYPE    STATUS      RECORDING   DURATION
14:52:54 UTC 
2016-11-29     Outgoing Dial    (512) xxx-xxxx   +91xxxxxxxxxx  Phone   No Answer   —            —

14:52:53 UTC 
2016-11-29     Incoming         Anonymous         —             Client  Completed   —           37 secs
```

Also when I click on the call details of the incoming call from logs, it is showing that the Call Cost is $0.0025.

2) Why is it charging even if I'm not answering the call?

Please help me to clarify these doubts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please paste (the relevant parts of) _your_ code into the question, because a) links can go dead, and b) it proves you didn't miss something from the example...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The connection here is:

```
+---------+                  +-------+
| browser | <--- Twilio ---> | phone |
+---------+                  +-------+
```

You are being charged for both legs of the call, from Twilio to the phone, and from Twilio to the browser. (I'm assuming you're at least having the browser "ring", or otherwise some connection to the browser is involved.)

> 2) Why is it charging even if I'm not answering the call?

Because they can/that's what they do. Even ringing the phone uses resources/costs money, so you're being charged.