# While using Elastic SIP Trunking will Twilio still charge though the call was not received or answered?

Tags: twilio

We've built a softphone system with Twilio Rest API and quickstart.js. But we are facing now a vital issue that Twilio is charging us for just an established call though it is not received! And we got the answer here [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40870135/call-charging-for-non-answered-calls-twilio) . So we searched for the solution and found out "**Elastic SIP Trunking**" that need some VoIP system or IP-PBX configurations.

But we are still confused and the question arises here, "While using Elastic SIP Trunking will Twilio still charge as the same though the call was not received  or answered?" .

Comment: What is the use case?

Comment: It's for calling from SIP to PSTN / Mobile Phones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Programmable Voice, there are usually 2 call legs. With the Twilio client, you have the leg into Twilio (where you tell Twilio via TwiML what to do next) and another leg to the PSTN (your TwiML told Twilio to dial the PSTN). Twilio bridges the two call legs together. Each call leg has a per minute cost associated with it.

In your example, the call leg from the Twilio client to Twilio is always successful/answered. The leg to the PSTN may or may not be successful. If the PSTN leg is busy or not answered, there is no charge for that call leg, only the Twilio client to Twilio leg incurs a cost.

[How Much am I Charged for Call Forwarding with Twilio?](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132367-How-Much-am-I-Charged-for-Call-Forwarding-with-Twilio-)

For the most part, Elastic SIP Trunking does not have call legs. You do need a call server/PBX to use Elastic SIP Trunks. The call server/PBX handles all the application functionality vs. Twilio with Programmable Voice.